# Replacing an old capacitor

Tags: capacitor, replacement

I've managed to blow a capacitor while doing maintenance on my 1967 electric organ. It's a 80uf 25V. I've done some searching and found that I can replace it with one that has a higher voltage rating but the same farad value. Is there anything else that I need to know before I buy a replacement? I've read some things about ripple current and resistance? The numbers on the capacitor are:
B41283-s5806-z2
80uf 25V
A 0-507-24
W9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very likely any 80 µF capacitor you can find today rated at 25 V or more will work fine in this situation.  Such a capacitor from 1967 is electrolytic, so already polarized.  Replacing it with a 80 µF 35 V, for example, modern capacitor should no result in any problems.

Comment: EE in training, here. Isn't it true that electrolytic perform better around their rated voltage? So he should go with a 25V?

Comment: no always better to have at least 20% margin  higher V ratings also tend to have lower ESR

Comment: @BrianDohler, I remember being told that electrolytics should have at least 10% of rated voltage across them but I couldn't find much to back that up when I once read around. So I'd say putting a 35V in should be fine.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm not sure where I heard that and I couldn't find anything to back it up either.

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys! Any idea where I could purchase one from? The places I found will only sell 50 or 100 at a time

Comment: @TonyM: There is some truth to what you say.  Keeping some voltage on electrolytics helps preserve the oxide layer that is the dielectric.  It's not much of a issue with modern capacitors, though.  I only mentioned 35 V since that's a common voltage today.  I would expect a 25 V cap to already be derated properly in the original design.  Changing from 25 to 35 V really shouldn't be any issue.  It's not a large change

Comment: @Creek: There are plenty of distributors that sell small quantities.  Check out Mouser as one example.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, yes I think you're right and I forgot to say earlier that I've always tried to keep at least 50% of the rated voltage on a smoothing/decoupling electrolytic.

Answer (score 8):

A 80µF electrolytic capacitor from 1967 could be easily 120uF back then, and 40µF today. It probably had a much higher internal resistance than modern capacitors. I think any good quality 100µF 25V is okay. You may of course use 100µF 35V or higher voltage. If you still prefer 80µF, that is okay, but I really think that 80µF or 100µF does not matter.

Do you know how old tube radios are repaired ? Every capacitor is cut away and replaced, without testing them if they are bad or still a little okay.

Comment: Not just tube radios. This is standard procedure for vintage valve hifi.